# mfc How can Child dialog know if Parent dialog push "cancel" button?

Tags: mfc, dialog

I made Child dialog in Parent dialog's tab control like this.
[dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Itai.png)

Child dialog uses database, so it has to be "db.Close()" when I push Parent dialog's "cancel" button.

In this case, How can Child dialog know if Parent dialog push "cancel" button?

OR...

How can Child dialog know right before destroyed by Parent dialog?

Comment: Why don't you run `db.Close()` in your child dialog's destructor?

Comment: Finally I inserted in PostNcDestroy() and it worked!

Comment: But why not place it in a C++ destructor? The C++ destructor executes no matter how the object goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

1) You could make a message handler in child's class and send it a message from it's parrent.

2) Other way is to make a public method in child's class who clears the window when DB is closed. From the parent call this method on child's object.

The first is much better and much safer solution.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try message handler